# jquery changing cell color on radio button selection

Tags: jquery

Just learning jquery and cannot get this to work.  I want to change the color of the cell when the "NO" radio button is clicked.  This is my best guess as to how it should work, but it is not.

I am loading this table dynamically, so I do not want to give each table cell a unique name.  I am trying to just effect the cell that the radio button is contained in using jquery's "this" to avoid using IDs.

```
<input type="radio" name="group20" value="2" class="spacer" onchange="radio()"> No 


<script>
    function radio() {
        $("td".this).toggleClass("no_checked");
    }
</script>
```

CSS:

```
.no_checked {background: #F5A9A9;}
```

Comment: `$("td".this)` should be `$("td")`

Comment: That actually worked, first time I've seen the color change.  However, it changed the entire table to red, and I only want to change that specific cell to red.

Comment: Give it an ID so instead of `$("td")` use `$("#whateverID")`

Comment: There will be over 40 rows in this table, loaded dynamically. I didnt want to have to give each one a different id.  That is why I was trying to use the "td".this

I think I may be misunderstanding how to use jquery's this.

Comment: try `$(this).closest('td')`

Comment: Your Question is very unclear. Try update it.

Comment: Updated.  also `$(this).closest("td").toggleClass("no_checked"); ` is not working.

Comment: Check the answer I posted

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code below adds and removes the class from the parent `td`.

**JQuery:**

```
$('input:radio[value=0]').click(function () {
    var $this = $(this);
    $this.closest('td').removeClass('no_checked');
});
$('input:radio[value=1]').click(function () {
    var $this = $(this);
    $this.closest('td').removeClass('no_checked');
});
$('input:radio[value=2]').click(function () {
    var $this = $(this);
    $this.closest('td').addClass('no_checked');
});
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/66FhT/4/)**

Comment: One step closer, but this turns every cell with a radio button to red.

Comment: No, every checked radio button's cell

Comment: Please create a full JSFiddle so I can check it for you

Comment: That definitely works. Now I have to go understand why.  Thank you.

Comment: Updated it once more for you! so now if the user clicks back on yes or NA it will remove the class